# SQL Server calculating age from varchar date of birth

Tags: sql, sql-server

The stored procedure is provided with `@minAge` and `@maxAge` `varchar` values.

The table contains `DOB` column as a `varchar`, now I need to select rows where where `DOB` (Age) falls between minimum and maximum age.

For instance `@minAge = 12` and `@maxAge = 40`, we have to first convert the `DOB` string into Current Age and then only select the rows which fall between (inclusive) of 12 and 40.

I have the following code in mind but that produces errors

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE
    FLOOR((CAST(GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(DOB AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age
      BETWEEN CAST(@minage AS INT) AND CAST(@maxAge AS INT)
```

Comment: Why, why, why is date of birth stored as a varchar? ***DATE*** of birth is a ***DATE***.

Comment: You should consider adding a `from` clause and other accoutrements of proper SQL.

Comment: i have imported the data from a different source its always been varchar, so i have to work with what i have got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of calculating the age is this:

```
DATEDIFF(YY, CAST(dob AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN( (MONTH(CAST(dob AS DATETIME))*100 + DAY(CAST(dob AS DATETIME))) > (MONTH(GETDATE())*100 + DAY(GETDATE())) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Age
```

where `dob` is the date of birth stored as varchar (in a way that can be cast to a datetime).

An example:

```
declare @people table(name varchar(20), dob varchar(10))
insert @people values ('adam', '1970-01-01')
insert @people values ('burt', '2002-01-13')
insert @people values ('dave', '1992-11-13')
insert @people values ('eric', '1973-11-13')

SELECT 
    name, 
    DATEDIFF(YY, CAST(dob AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN( (MONTH(dob)*100 + DAY(dob)) > (MONTH(GETDATE())*100 + DAY(GETDATE())) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Age
FROM @people 
WHERE DATEDIFF(YY, dob, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN( (MONTH(dob)*100 + DAY(dob)) > (MONTH(GETDATE())*100 + DAY(GETDATE())) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
BETWEEN 12 AND 40
```

This would be the result:

```
name    Age
burt    12
dave    21
eric    40
```

This might not be the best way though, but it should work.

Comment: You should throw a leap year in there too to be safe (and also test when your date falls on a leap 29th). I don't know if either case fails, but it's a good test to be sure they don't.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's a good idea. I didn't test it that much so the calculation might very well be off.